# In tomcat version 8.5.88, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener occurs

Tags: tomcat, cluster-analysis

In tomcat version 8.5.88, java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.tomcat.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener occurs.

My settings are like this

```
  <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster" channelSendOptions="6" channelStartOptions="3">
        <Manager className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.DeltaManager" expireSessionsOnShutdown="false" notifyListenersOnReplication="true" />
            <Channel className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.GroupChannel">
                <Receiver className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.NioReceiver"
                          autoBind="0" selectorTimeout="5000" maxThreads="6"
                          address="127.0.0.1" port="4001" />
                <Sender className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.ReplicationTransmitter">
                   <Transport className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.transport.nio.PooledParallelSender"
                              timeout="60000"
                              keepAliveTime="10"
                              keepAliveCount="0"
                   />
                </Sender>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpPingInterceptor" staticOnly="true"/>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.TcpFailureDetector"/>
                <Interceptor className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.group.interceptors.StaticMembershipInterceptor">
                    <Member className="org.apache.catalina.tribes.membership.StaticMember"
                            host="127.0.0.1"
                            port="4002"
                            uniqueId="{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1}"/>
                </Interceptor>
            </Channel>
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.ReplicationValve" filter="" />
        <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteBinderValve" />
<ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener"/>
            
        <ClusterListener className="org.apache.catalina.ha.session.ClusterSessionListener"/>
  </Cluster>
```

without any other settings
 If only the settings are put in, it will start normally, but if the full settings are put in, it will not start and a classNotFound error will occur.
I checked that it was deflated in version 8.0 or higher, but I think it should be started normally, but it doesn't start even though there is a class.
Have you ever experienced a situation like this?

expected to work normally even without org.apache.tomcat.ha.session.JvmRouteSessionIDBinderListener, but I am curious about which class replaced the operation performed by that class and why it does not start.